# How to open an Excel file which has been downloaded from my mailbox and extracted in Winzip successfully?

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing a project where I have met 2 conditions. I had to download a Winzip attachment from my mailbox and then extract it successfully and then open that file. I have done the first 2 parts, but I'm not able to open the file. The problem is with the name of the file. I am not able to specify the name of the file in the macro. The below is the code used:

```
Sub FebAttachment_Click()
Const olFolderInbox As Integer = 6
Const AttachmentPath As String = "D:\Documents and Settings\rahul.baskaran\Desktop\"
Dim oApp As Object, ONS As Object, OInb As Object
Dim OItem, OAtch As Object
Dim OFind As Object
Dim OMail As Object


Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
Set ONS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set OInb = ONS.Folders("Archive Folders").Folders("BIZOPS").Folders("2014.02")
Set OMail = OInb.Items

For Each OItem In OInb.Items

    If OItem.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each OAtch In OItem.Attachments
            OAtch.SaveAsFile AttachmentPath & OAtch.Filename
            Exit For
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "The mail doesn't have an attachment"
        End If
Exit For
Next`

Dim FSO As Object
Dim Fname As Variant
Dim FileNameFolder As Variant
Dim DefPath As Variant
Dim EXCELApplication As Object



 Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Zip Files (*.zip), *.zip", _
                                    MultiSelect:=False)

If Fname = False Then
    'Do nothing
Else

    DefPath = "D:\Documents and Settings\rahul.baskaran\Desktop\"
    If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        DefPath = DefPath & "\"
    End If

    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    oApp.Namespace(DefPath).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname).Items
    DoEvents


Set EXCELApplication = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
EXCELApplication.Workbooks.Open (DefPath & "\22 ABC Feb BVA as of 25th-Nov-13 Sigma .xlsb")
EXCELApplication.Visible = True

 End Sub
```

Everything is working as expected with this code. But in the below line. I want to automate the name of the file and then open the file. I am not able to perform this operation.

`EXCELApplication.Workbooks.Open (DefPath & "\22 ABC Feb BVA as of 25th-Nov-13 Sigma .xlsb")`

Can someone help me with the below 2 points?

**1) Is it possible to extract the file without me manually selecting the file using the Application.GetOpenFilename function?**

**2) I want the extracted file to be opened automatically once its extracted successfully. Any other method of coding is welcome as well.**

Comment: Check if the file actually exists. Also `22 ABC Feb BVA as of 25th-Nov-13 Sigma .xlsb` you have a SPACE before `.xlsb` Are you sure the actual file has that space?

Comment: Hey again, Siddharth. Yes, the file has a space at the end. And its present in the zip file which I extracted successfully. How do I open this file?

Comment: I mean after extracting it, can you see if it is there in the desktop?

Comment: Yes. I can. Also I receive this mail every week and the name keeps changing. So I can't use some constant to open the file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with that line is the extra `\`

`DefPath` already evaluates to `"D:\Documents and Settings\rahul.baskaran\Desktop\"` so `DefPath & "\22 ABC Feb BVA as of 25th-Nov-13 Sigma .xlsb"` will give you

`D:\Documents and Settings\rahul.baskaran\Desktop\\22 ABC Feb BVA as of 25th-Nov-13 Sigma .xlsb"`

Notice the `\\` before `22`? Change your code to

`EXCELApplication.Workbooks.Open (DefPath & "22 ABC Feb BVA as of 25th-Nov-13 Sigma .xlsb")`

Comment: Hey Sid.. Thanks for that. But even with the extra '\', I didn't have problem opening the file. Also, what I'm looking for here is to open the extracted file.. And as I told, the name of file keeps changing everytime. So I need to somehow put the name of the file in some variable and then use it in the below statement instead of directly specifying the path name.


`\22 ABC Feb BVA as of 25th-Nov-13 Sigma .xlsb`